# #1064-you have an error in SQL syntax: check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

```sql
create TABLE product
(
    productid int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    productname varchar(100) not null,
    productdesc varchar(100)not null,
    productrate double(100) not null,
    imagea varchar(100) not null,
    imageb varchar(100) not null,
    imagec varchar(100)  not null 
) type=MyISAM
```

[these images contains query and the error displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncIEy.jpg)

Comment: can you post actual query in question.

Comment: I had given a image see there. Just click    "the image's contains query and the error".

Comment: Change Type=MyISAM to Engine=MyISAM.

Comment: Will Walsh I tried it but it doesn't work pls any other suggestions

Comment: I'm pretty sure your DOUBLE(100) data type is not valid, as well ....   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html

Comment: Thank you Craig it worked with float and giving primary key

Comment: I'd recommend to use not approximate FLOAT/DOUBLE but precise DECIMAL.

Comment: Why are you using MyISAM anyway?

Answer (score -2):

```
create TABLE product
(
    productid int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    productname varchar(100) not null,
    productdesc varchar(100)not null,
    productrate float(25) not null,
    imagea varchar(100) not null,
    imageb varchar(100) not null,
    imagec varchar(100)  not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(productid)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

Thankyou Craig and thank you for all for replying me to solve this.